# Removing space between objects of a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, d3, topojson, mapshaper

I'm trying to visualise the results french presidential elections of 2017 by departments (meaning states). I found a shapefile of France with departments [here](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/contours-des-departements-francais-issus-d-openstreetmap/)

When I try to export this file in TopoJSON format from [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org) it has a lot of space between mainland France and some of the departments.

[image]

Is there a way I could make it look like this

[image]

Comment: having the departements *not* in that place is kind of the point of spatial data...it's possible, though, so maybe someone actually went this way... however, usually you have the application create individual containers to present different features of your data in an order like that above (or use a prerendered image).

Comment: Please state your d3 version and post code that you have tried and that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using D3 v4 and the code can be found [here](https://github.com/atharvat80/D3_Assignment) it's in `script.js`. I'm currenty using a different topojson file that I found somewhere else which doesn't include all of the departements but it does job for now :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `d3` the correct way to do this is to use a composite [projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection). Here are plug-ins that specify composite projections for France:

- https://github.com/rveciana/d3-composite-projections (d3v4 and d3v3)
- https://github.com/seeschloss/francedom (unmaintained as of 20.12.2019)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can physically move the polygons of the outer territories in geographic data, but this would degrade data unnecessarily.

The much better solution hinted at by [@ThingumaBob](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345475/how-do-i-remove-space-between-objects-of-a-shapefile/345532#comment564511_345475) is to simply use multiple map frames when designing your export. Create a map frame for each outlying territory, then move those around on your sheet layout for printing/viewing the result version. This also allows you to use different scales for each departement, add labels and much more, if desired.

Check [the QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html) on how to accomplish this.

As a basic rule: Most GIS will separate data exploration and analysis from actually rendering and exporting map products, because there are many very valid reasons to depart from geographic 'truth' for the sake of readability of a map product.

Comment: The question is tagged #d3, but this answer refers to QGIS.